# If all reals are generic, is the set of reals generic?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

Let $W\subseteq V$ be two models of $\sf ZFC$ with the same ordinals. Is the following situation consistent:

1. For every $x\in\Bbb R^V$ there is some $P_x\in W$ such that for some $G\subseteq P_x$ which is $W$-generic, $x\in W[G]$.
2. There is no $P\in W$ and $G\subseteq P$ that is $W$-generic such that $\Bbb R^{W[G]}=\Bbb R^V$.

Namely, each real is [set-]generic over $W$, but the set of reals is not.

This sort of situation of course immediately exclude the case that $V$ is a generic extension of $W$; but also things like when $V=L[r]$ is obtained by coding $W$ into a real $r$.

(We may assume that $\sf CH$ holds in $V$, otherwise we can force it without adding real numbers.)

Comment: What happens if we consider the following: Let $(x_i: i<c^V)$ enumerate $\mathbb{R}^V,$ and for each $i$ let $P_i=P_{x_i}.$ What if we let $P$ be the product of $P_i$'s, $i < c^V$?

Comment: Then you've added all the reals. But perhaps many more. And it's not clear to me why $\Bbb R^V$ is a set in that generic extension (or why this $P$ is even in $W$, actually).

Comment: Also, this $P$ depends greatly on the enumeration. What happens if the enumeration itself encodes many real numbers in $\Bbb R^V\setminus\Bbb R^W$? In that case it is guaranteed that $P$ is not in $W$. And such situation seems more than reasonable, I'd think.

Comment: Under your hypotheses, we can assume without loss of generality that all the $P_x$'s are the same, namely, the collapse forcing $\text{Coll}(\omega,\delta)$ of some fixed $\delta$ to $\omega$. This is because any forcing notion embeds into this, for sufficiently large $\delta$, and we may simply take $\delta$ large enough to work for all $x$.

Comment: @Joel: That's a great observation!

Comment: @Joel: Does that mean that for some $W$-generic $G\subseteq \operatorname{Coll}(\omega,\delta)$, $\Bbb R^V\in W[G]$? If the answer is positive, I don't see why.

Comment: I don't see that yet. But I can show that $\mathbb{R}^V\subset W[H]$ for some $W$-generic $H$ (and this is not so easy as just taking a product as in the comments above, since you've got to take mutual genericity into account). My original idea was that this might be suffficient, by considering $W\subset W(\mathbb{R}^V)\subset W[H]$ and trying to apply the intermediate model theorem to realize $W(\mathbb{R}^V)$ as a forcing extension of $W$, combined with the fact that it is contained in $V$. But $W(\mathbb{R}^V)$ is only a ZF model, and so the intermediate model theorem does not apply.

Comment: @Joel: Well, $W(\Bbb R^V)$ might not be an inner model of $W[H]$ anyway, if $\Bbb R^V$ is not a set there. So even if it was a model of $\sf ZFC$, I'm still not sure how you can apply the theorem.

Comment: Yes, indeed, that idea just doesn't work.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, do you want the generics $G \subseteq P_x$ to be members of $V$?  If so, Joel's observation about $\mathrm{Coll}(\omega,\delta)$ might not be relevant.

Comment: @Monroe: One can assume without loss of generality that each real defines a generic.

Comment: Oh right, by intermediate model theorem.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, How do you show that $\mathbb{R}^V \subseteq W[H]$ for some $W$-generic $H$?

Comment: @MonroeEskew I make the claim only for countable models. This follows as a consequence of theorem 34 in my paper, "Set-theoretic geology" (http://jdh.hamkins.org/set-theoreticgeology/), which says that one can get above any countable sequence of successive forcing extensions of a countable model $W$, if the forcing has bounded size in $W$. There is also a more hands-on proof for this case, which simplifies some of the generalities of that proof.

Comment: It also follows directly from corollary 36 in that paper, if you consider the extensions $W[x]$ for a real $x\in\mathbb{R}^V$, since these are finitely amalgamable (again assuming these are countable models of set theory).

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, thanks for the reference.  Looks like a very interesting paper.  Nice and clear argument for Theorem 34.

Comment: Shouldn't (2) say "for _some_ $G\subseteq P$ that is $W$-generic, $\mathbb{R}^{W[G]} = \mathbb{R}^V$"?  Or is what's written equivalent to this somehow?

Comment: Another note: We can always take $V$ to be $W[x]$ for some $x \subset \omega_1.$ To see this, consider the given $V$. Force over it to force $GCH$. The resulting generic extension adds no new reals. Force over the extension by Jensen's coding to code every thing into a subset $x$ of $\omega_1.$ Again we do not add new reals and the final model is of the form $L[x]=W[x].$ So $V$ and $W[x]$ have the same reals and we can replace $V$ by $W[x].$

Comment: @Mohammad: I actually thought about that, and the first thing I figured was that such example would be a solution, only later I realized that my argument is wrong, so I came to ask it here. But that is an excellent remark, thank you for making it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I met Woodin recently and asked him that. He came up with a solution, modulo some technical assumption which Ashutosh [showed to be consistent](https://mathoverflow.net/a/220853/7206) (although admittedly, not the same suggestion that Woodin had for solving this issue). With his kind permission, I am posting this solution here.

1. $W$ is a model of $\sf ZFC+GCH+$"There are $\aleph_1$ ccc forcings which add independent reals" (call these forcings $\Bbb P_\alpha$).
2. $V_1$ is a class generic extension of $W$ in which a proper class of cardinals were collapsed while preserving $\sf ZFC$ (e.g. collapse all $\aleph_{\alpha\cdot\omega+3}$ to $\aleph_{\alpha\cdot\omega+2}$).
3. $V_2$ is coding $V_1$ into a subset of $\omega_1$ without adding reals over $W$, so $V_2=W[A]$ where $A\subseteq\omega_1$.
4. Finally, $V$ is the finite support product of $\Bbb P_\alpha$ for $\alpha\in A$ over $V_2$.

Since from $W$ to $V_2$ we didn't add any reals, and every real added to $V$ came from a countable part of the product (which is in $W$), it follows that every real number is $W$-generic for some suitable part of the product. But if you had a $W$-generic $G$ (for a set forcing) such that $W[G]$ and $V$ had the same reals, you would be able to extract $A$ and therefore compute the class generic for the now-collapsed cardinals.

Comment: That's a nice argument.

Comment: What was Woodin's example for $W$ in 1?

Comment: @Ashutosh: $L$ with selective ultrafilters.

Comment: What are the $P_i$'s?

Comment: @Ashutosh: Shooting fast sets through the selective ultrafilters.

Comment: Sorry I cannot see what's happening here. Can you give some details?

Comment: @Ashutosh: In what part?

Comment: The definition of $P_i$'s.

Comment: @Ashutosh: Those are the $\Bbb P_\alpha$ from *your* answer. It's an $\aleph_1$-family of c.c.c. forcings that adding a generic for any countably many (with finite support product) will not add any generic for any other $\Bbb P_\alpha$.

Comment: I meant what was Woodin's way of doing it with selective ultrafilters?

Comment: @Ashutosh: Oh, he suggested picking a family of $\aleph_1$ selective ultrafilters, and use the fact they are minimal to show that if you shoot a fast set through countably many, you don't add fast sets through the rest. When I met him again in Jerusalem, I told him that everyone agreed off-hand it's a reasonable strategy but the details seem overly gruesome; he insisted it should be fine, and also suggested using independent $(\omega_1,\omega_1)$-gaps instead which are relatively easy to come by. But as long as there is one example, the idea works, and you provided that nice example anyway.

Comment: I have several issues with this. What selective u.f. do you pick? What is "shooting a fast set through an ultrafilter" (I know Mathias forcing guided by an ultrafilter but is that what it is)? Anyhow, I was thinking about your question on whether there is a ZFC example of independent forcings and wondered if Woodin's example could be used to give a positive answer, that's all.